# What's wrong with this cassandra prepared statement call?

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax

I'm using the datastax cassandra driver for python.

The portion of the code at issue is:

```
cql = "SELECT * FROM iptools.geo2ip WHERE geo_key = ? AND (( geohash >= ? AND geohash < ? ) OR ( geohash >= ? AND geohash < ? ));"
print cql
prepared = self.session.prepare(cql)
```

Results are:

```
SELECT * FROM iptools.geo2ip WHERE geo_key = ? AND (( geohash >= ? AND geohash < ? ) OR ( geohash >= ? AND geohash < ? ));
cassandra.protocol.SyntaxException: <ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:82 missing EOF at ')' (...? AND geohash < ? [)];)">
```

I'm not sure where the brackets around the parenthesis are coming from, and the prepare statement works as soon as I remove the parenthesis.

Ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is happening because CQL does not contain a definition for the `OR` keyword.

Comment: That and parenthesis don't really work the same in CQL as they do in SQL.  I'd get rid of them all together.

Comment: Could you post your `CREATE TABLE geo2ip` statement?  That'll help in figuring out how to get what you're looking for.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 - if you want to make your "OR" statement as an answer, I'll accept it.  It was the problem.
I'll just make multiple queries.  Now I get to deal with fixing what I think is a bloom table caused memory issue - I'm running out of heap space when doing range queries - across about 2 billion rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is happening because CQL does not contain a definition for the `OR` keyword.  One shortcut that has been used in place of `OR`, is `IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM geo2ip WHERE geo_key IN (?,?);
```

Although be forewarned that `IN` is known to not perform very well.  However, I don't think that will help you much anyway, as it looks like you want to be able to do a range query on `geohash`.  Depending on your PRIMARY KEY definition (for instance, with `geo_key` as the partition key and `geohash` as the clustering key`), this (minus the complex`OR` logic) should still work:

```
SELECT * FROM iptools.geo2ip WHERE geo_key = ? AND geohash >= ? AND geohash < ?;
```